# How to mathematically prove that a relation T(n)=T($\sqrt{n}$)+c is O(log(log(n))?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16472012/what-would-cause-an-algorithm-to-have-olog-log-n-complexity), I understood the intuition behind how cutting down the size of input by square root on each iteration leads to O(log(log(n))) complexity.

I tried to derive it on paper.

Let T(n) = T($\sqrt{n}$) + c
$\implies$ T($n^{1/2}$)+2c
$\implies$ T($n^{1/4}$)+3c
$\implies$ T($n^{1/8}$)+4c
$\implies$ T($n^{1/16}$)+5c
.....upto n > 1

I noticed that the power of n becomes 1/2 times the last value.

How should I proceed from here on?
I need to derive that T(n) is O(log(log(n))).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers). Specifically: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/105833/68251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, you can show inductively that $T(n) = T(n^{1/2^k}) + kc$, with base case $T(n) = O(1)$ for $n \leq 2$ (say). It follows that $T(n) = \Theta(\ell)$, where $\ell$ is the minimal number such that $n^{1/2^\ell} \leq 2$. Taking a log, we get $\frac{\log n}{2^\ell} \leq 1$, or $\log n \leq 2^\ell$. Taking another log, we get $\log \log n \leq \ell$. Hence $\ell = \lceil \log\log n \rceil$, and it follows that $T(n) = \Theta(\log\log n)$.

Comment: Hi, the input will decrease from some positive quantity to 2 and below. The base case is T(1) = O(1) for n<=2. So did you meant $n^{1/2^\ell} \geq 2$

Comment: I think the inequality is in the correct direction.

Comment: $n^\frac{1}{2^\ell} \le 2$ is correct. Notice that  $n^\frac{1}{2^\ell}$ is monotonically decreasing as $\ell$ increases. For all values of $\ell$ that are bigger than some $\ell_0$, $n^\frac{1}{2^\ell}$ will be less than $2$. You are looking for $\ell_0$, i.e., the minimum (integer) value of $\ell$ for which $n^\frac{1}{2^\ell} \le 2$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = \log n$ and $Q(x) = T(2^x)$. You can rewrite your recurrence as follows:
$$
Q(x) = T(2^x) = T(n) = T(n^\frac{1}{2}) + c = T(2^{x/2}) + c = Q(x/2) + c.
$$

Which is easily solved using, e.g., the Master Theorem to obtain $Q(x) = \Theta(\log x)$. Substituting back:
$$
T(n) = Q(x) = \Theta(\log x) = \Theta(\log \log n).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Define S(k) = $T(2^{2^k})$.

Then S(k) = $T(2^{2^k})$ = $T(2^{2^{k-1}}) + c$ = $T(2^{2^{k-2}}) + 2c$ = ...  = $T(2^{2^{k-k}}) + k\cdot c$ = $T(2) + k\cdot c$.